Remove small corners for polygon
I have polygons with holes where I'd like to remove the small corners.

The left part is the original polygon. As shown,the white part are holes. While the corner in the red circle should be removed. There are two types of corners in the example: A and B. For corner A, the coordinates should be re-calculated, and for corner B, the vertices should be removed. The right part is the expected result:
1 Is there a terminology for this kind of processing ?
2 If not, any idea for design the algorithm ?
